# Website structure changing when I change pc

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made all the webpages in `html5`, `css` and `js` and used google chrome to see the result.

When I change the pc for example, the structure of the webpage changes completely...

I think it has something to do with position relative and absolute but not sure...

Here it is [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pXzuX),  the webpage for now is just 5 images that I can navigate with 4 keys from keyboard,

sorry for my english...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're looking for magicians, you've came to the wrong place. Please show some code where it breaks, a fiddle or similar.

Comment: Could you provide some code and HTML?

Comment: I suggest using jsfiddle.com to post the code you're using, so someone might recognize the flaw.

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/pXzuX/, the webpage for now is just 5 images that I can navigate with 4 keys from keyboard, sorry for my english...

Comment: Can you please give us a working fiddle??

Comment: if you are on PC do CTRL+0 to reset the browser or hold CTRL and use the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Are the screens different 'sizes'. Check the resolution of the displays. That's most likely your issue.

It sounds like you're positioning your elements based on the size of your screen. This would be fine if everyone had your screen.

If you could provide your code, I could further assist on how to remedy your situation.

In the meantime, try reading more into css positioning: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: Here it is jsfiddle.net/pXzuX, the webpage for now is just 5 images that I can navigate with 4 keys from keyboard, sorry for my english...

Comment: You should put your images in a div and remove the positioning on the individual images. Then absolute position the div, which has all the images inside, using percentages for the left/right/top/bottom values to position it how you want.